# Is it possible see the interiors of the Dome of the Rock?

Tags: israel, architecture, religion, islam, jerusalem

Is it possible to visit [Dome of the Rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dome_of_the_Rock) for non-muslim tourists these days?
Last time I tried was in 2005, and back then it wasn't.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dome_of_the_Rock#Accessibility), the Dome of the Rock complex (Temple Mount) was reopened to non-Muslim visitors for limited time and days of the week (for example, non-Muslims are not allowed in on Fridays).

[Frommer's](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/jerusalem/0088032100.html) has a detailed description on how to get tourist access to the site. You may be able to get into the complex and the museum, but probably not into the actual dome.

Comment: I agree. Was in Jerusalem in March and got in to the complex no problem, but only practicing Muslims can enter the actual structure